# Why is Nokogiri returning blank output to excel?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

**My task**

Extract all specifications from http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/ASUS_TAICHI_21/#specifications and put it in a spreadsheet (we work on formatting later)

**Problem**

Spreadsheet is created but my output is returning blank.

**My Code**

```
require 'Nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'spreadsheet'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/ASUS_TAICHI_21/#specifications"))

data = puts doc.css('//div#specifications/div#spec-area/ul#product-spec/li')

Spreadsheet.client_encoding = 'UTF-8'
book = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new

sheet1 = book.create_worksheet
sheet1.name = 'My First Worksheet'

sheet1[0,0] = data
book.write 'C:/Users/Barry/Desktop/output.xls'
```

**The following code worked for me**

```
require 'Nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'spreadsheet'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/ASUS_TAICHI_21/#specifications"))

data = doc.css('div#specifications div#spec-area ul.product-spec')[0].text

Spreadsheet.client_encoding = 'UTF-8'
book = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new

sheet1 = book.create_worksheet
sheet1.name = 'My First Worksheet'

sheet1[0,0] = data
book.write 'C:/Users/Barry/Desktop/output.xls'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems here:

1. It looks like you’re trying to debug by printing out the result of the `css` call in the line:

   ```
   data = puts doc.css('//div#specifications/div#spec-area/ul#product-spec/li')
   ```

   The method [`puts`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-puts) returns `nil`, so `data` will be `nil` and will result in nothing being shown.
2. In the page you’re parsing, the `product-spec` list is in fact a class, not an id, so you need `.product-spec` (`.` instead of `#`).
3. The syntax you’re using isn’t actually CSS, it looks like you’re mixing CSS and Xpath. You want something like this:

   ```
   doc.css('div#specifications div#spec-area ul.product-spec li')
   ```

   (This last point doesn’t seem to actually affect the result. Nokogiri converts CSS selectors to xpath and it appears that the transformation results in valid xpath anyway).

Comment: That was it! Thanks for that. Nokogiri has sparse documentation, very frustrating.